How to disable all buttons on a interaction using discordgo?
I've created a tic-tac-toe game in golang utilizing the discordgo library. I am attempting to disable all the buttons after a winner to prevent someone from spamming them, but no matter what I try I just cannot seem to get the buttons to actually disable. They disable just fine when a move is placed, but not when it's won. It will go all the way to the 'third' print statement and then just not continue. Here is the winning code:
if winner != "" {
        content := fmt.Sprintf("> Game over! Winner: <@%s>", winner)
        for _, component := range components {
            fmt.Println("reached first")
            if actionRow, ok := component.(*discordgo.ActionsRow); ok {
                fmt.Println("reached second")
                for i, comp := range actionRow.Components {
                    fmt.Printf("Component type: %T\n", comp)
                    fmt.Println("Reached third")
                    if button, ok := comp.(*discordgo.Button); ok {
                        fmt.Printf("Component type (index %d): %T\n", i, comp) 
                        fmt.Println(ok)
                        fmt.Println("Got")
                        fmt.Println(button)
                        button.Disabled = true  // Disable the button
                        actionRow.Components[i] = button  // Assign the disabled button back to the row
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        s.InteractionRespond(i.Interaction, &discordgo.InteractionResponse{
            Type: discordgo.InteractionResponseUpdateMessage,
            Data: &discordgo.InteractionResponseData{
                Content:    content,
                Components: components,
            },
        })
        fmt.Println("went down to this line")
        delete(cmd.games, gameID)
        return

and here is what components is (it calls a function)

func (cmd *TicTacToeCommand) makeGameBoardComponents(gameID string) []discordgo.MessageComponent {
    game, exists := cmd.games[gameID]
    if !exists {
        return nil
    }

    var components []discordgo.MessageComponent
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        var row []discordgo.MessageComponent
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            label := game.board[i][j]
            if label == " " {
                label = "‎"
            }
            button := discordgo.Button{
                Label:    label,
                CustomID: fmt.Sprintf("move:%s:%d:%d", gameID, i, j),
                Style:    discordgo.SecondaryButton,
                Disabled: label != "‎", //invisable text, [U+200E]
            }
            row = append(row, button)
        }
        components = append(components, &discordgo.ActionsRow{Components: row})
    }
    return components
}

